# Doesn't connect css files in my project based Spring boot

Tags: java, css, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

Tell me why I can't connect the css files in my index.html. [image]

I have tried various methods, but nothing has worked.
In my project Spring Security...maybe it somehow affects.

My WebSecurityConfig class

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
  // @Autowired
 //  UserService userService;

@Bean
public BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
    httpSecurity
            .csrf()
            .disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/resources/**").permitAll()
            //Доступ только для не зарегистрированных пользователей
            .antMatchers("/","/index","/login","/registration").permitAll()
            //Доступ только для пользователей с ролью Администратор
            .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
            .antMatchers("/news").hasRole("USER")
            //Доступ разрешен всем пользователей
            .antMatchers("/", "/resources/**").permitAll()
            //Все остальные страницы требуют аутентификации
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            //Настройка для входа в систему
            .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login")
            //Перенарпавление на главную страницу после успешного входа
            .defaultSuccessUrl("/")
            .permitAll()
            .and()
            .logout()
            .permitAll()
            .logoutSuccessUrl("/");
}
```

And this is how I connected in various ways in index.html

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../resources/styles/bootstrap-4.1.2/bootstrap.min.css">
<link href="../../resources/plugins/font-awesome-4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../resources/plugins/OwlCarousel2-2.3.4/owl.carousel.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../resources/plugins/OwlCarousel2-2.3.4/owl.theme.default.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../resources/plugins/OwlCarousel2-2.3.4/animate.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" th:href="@{../resources/styles/main_styles.css}">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" th:href="@{../resources/styles/responsive.css}">
```

I don’t understand why it doesn’t connect...

Comment: but I need him for the future.

Comment: Are you using the @EnableWebMvc annotation? If so, you might want to try removing it as a test. Or try {styles/main_styles...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't use resources in href, and by convention you put static files like css, js and such into `resources/static/`and then use `th:href="@{styles/main_styles.css}`

also just to make sure it isn't spring security blocking it, I always added following in my security config:

```
 @Override
 public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/resources/**", "/static/**", "/css/**", "/js/**", "/images/**","/vendor/**","/fonts/**").anyRequest(); 
 }
```

ps:
Btw I couldnt help but notice - dnt use package names in plural - convention is singular so not `controllers` but `controller`. You have to think that package name will be read as a whole line `com.sportify.Sportify.controllers.HomeController` which will be then used in import statements

For the same reason only class name starts with capital letter and you shouldn't repeat package names - so correct would be `com.yoursuranme.sportify.controller` package structure. But this is just to provide info for future reference.

Comment: Thank you for your response, you are helping me a fool for the second time =) 
Did everything as you said, but the styles still didn't apply.
P.S. I didn't know about static, thanks

Comment: check out this for reference - it works for me https://github.com/asgarov1/springSecurityDemo

Comment: finally it worked =) This line helped me
  web.ignoring().antMatchers("/resources/**", "/static/**",
                "/css/**", "/js/**", "/images/**","/vendor/**","/fonts/**").anyRequest();
And before that I wrote only this
  web.ignoring().antMatchers("static/**");
Thank you very much for your time.